# Loop through class object in php?

Tags: php

I can figure out how to loop through a table from the database now that I converted to class it.

Old code

```php
<?php
$sql = "WHERE * FROM Somewere";
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
$products = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<?php foreach ($products as $product) ?>
```

New code

```php
<?php
class Posts extends Database
{
    public function postsToPost()
    {

        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare("WHERE * FROM Somewere");
        $stmt->execute();

        $products = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    }

}
?>

<?php foreach ($products as $product) ?>
```

Do I need now loop inside the class and then output in my page?
I'm confused.
Thanks

Comment: `$products` is in the local scope. Where do you make `Posts`? You should make a method var `public $products = '';` then `$this->products = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` then use that `products` from your `Posts` object. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Or you can just `return $products`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the result:

```
class Posts extends Database
{
    public function postsToPost()
    {

        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare("WHERE * FROM Somewere");
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    }

}
```

and then instantiate `Posts`, like this:

```
$posts = new Posts();
$products = $posts->postsToPost();
foreach ($products as $product);
```

Comment: @wiu you are welcome. It's not difficult, you just need to understand the basics. When you achieve that, all the more complex stuff will be understandable. If this answer solved your question, you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.